# Trying to find trapezoid volume

Tags: button, calculator, prompt, volume

Im still new to coding and still experimenting with different forms. I have been able to calculate the volume of a trapezoid using prompts but now I am looking to achieve the same effect using viewable inputs and buttons and the code keeps outputing a NaN so I was wondering if anyone can spot what it is I might be doing wrong here, anything helps!

```
<h1>Trapazoid Calculator</h1>
<br>

<br>
<label>Length</label>
<br>
<input id="Length" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" value=7>

<br>
<label>Height</label>
<br>
<input id="Height" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" value=7>

<br>
<label>Width</label>
<br>
<input id="Width" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" value=7>

<br>
<label>Top</label>
<br>
<input id="Top" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" value=7>

<br>
<br>
<input type = "button" id="button1" value="Calculate" onclick = "calculateTrapazoid()"/>
<input type = "reset" value="Clear" />



    <script>

        function calculateTrapazoid(){
        //retrieve elements
        var Length = document.getElementById("Length");
        var Height = document.getElementById("Height");
        var Width = document.getElementById("Width");
        var Top = document.getElementById("Top")

        //float elements?
        Length = parseFloat(Length);
        Height = parseFloat(Height);
        Width = parseFloat(Width);
        Top = parseFloat(Top);

        //formula
        var Volume = (Length)*(Height)*((Width+Top)*.5); 

        //output
        document.write("<p>The Volume is : "+Volume+"</p>");

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("Length")` returns the html DOM object

`document.getElementById("Length").value` returns the value contained in the DOM object which is what you're looking to do

More info on getElementById and the DOM https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Here's a working fiddle with the following code (in case the link doesn't work properly). https://jsfiddle.net/g43u9x7h/

```
<div>

<label>Data</label>
<br>
<input id="Top" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" placeholder='Top'>
<input id="Height" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" placeholder='Height'>
<input id="Width" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()" placeholder='Width'>
<input id="Length" type="number" onchange="Trapazoid()"  placeholder='Length'>
<br>
<br>
<input type = "button" id="button1" value="Calculate" onclick = "calculateTrapazoid()"/>
<input type = "reset" value="Clear" />
</div>

    <script>

        function calculateTrapazoid(){
        //retrieve elements
        var Length = document.getElementById("Length").value;
        var Height = document.getElementById("Height").value;
        var Width = document.getElementById("Width").value;
        var Top = document.getElementById("Top").value
        console.log(Length, typeof Length)

        //float elements?
        Length = parseFloat(Length);
        Height = parseFloat(Height);
        Width = parseFloat(Width);
        Top = parseFloat(Top);

        //formula
        console.log(Length, typeof Length)
        var Volume = (Length)*(Height)*((Width+Top)*.5); 

        //output
        document.write("<p>The Volume is : "+Volume+"</p>");

        }
    </script>
```